# Fetch API: Process only part of chunk data

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am fetching a large amount of data using the fetch API using streams but I want to process only the first 15MB of it.

I am creating a CSV file from the fetch data, however when I write the file, the file seems to be in not a valid state, the rows seem to be garbled.

Maybe because I am not processing the chunk boundaries correctly.

below is my code.

```
            const stream = await fetch(fetchUrl);
            let receivedLength = 0;
            let reader = stream.body.getReader();
            const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-16le');
            while(true) {
              const {done, value} = await reader.read();
              if (done || receivedLength >= 15000000) {
                break;
              }
              receivedLength += value.length;
              let v = decoder.decode(value, {stream: true});
           }
```

How do I process only part of data returned from fetch API and ensure the boundaries are preserved. Thanks

Comment: Where does `receivedLength` come from? What is you actual output?

Comment: The chunks you receive from `reader.read` don't necessarily align with your input structure, or even UTF-16 encoding. If a UTF-16 character is split between two chunks, your decoder will most certainly complain (and fail). You might want to look into a TransformStream to structure the input using a bit of buffering for trailing, incomplete data at the end of a chunk.

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt, i have updated the question. Added the missing `receivedLength` logic. The output file looks incomplete with regular column sizes. however when i process the full file the csv looks fine, its just when i process only part of received data the csv does not work as expected. May be when i exit the loop, the chunk received is incomplete and it messes up the csv

Comment: @Touffy, thanks for your reply. when i process all the chunks currently, it works fine as expected. the issue is when i exit out after x amount of data is received. My encoding is `utf-16le`. Can i still use TransformStream in this case?

Comment: Note that if the reader is at the end (`done` is true),  you're not going to decode the last `value`, unless you repeat that code after the `while(true)` block.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, yes, i want to not process any data after the total size of processed data exceeds 15Mb

Comment: Is it possible for you to fetch only 15mb from the server using `Range` header, or do you also need the remainder of the data?

Comment: @agathver, i dont need the remainder of data as of now.

Comment: If you target a very recent Chrome or Fx that support the [TextDecoderStream](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_textdecoderstream), you can use that.

Comment: @Touffy, thanks for your reply. Sorry i am new to usingh streams, which part in my above code should i replace with TextDecoderStream?

Comment: @opensource-developer You can try using the `Range` header to  exactly fetch  the amount of data you need.

Comment: @agathver, tried the `Range` header but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this answer assumes that you're targeting very modern browsers that support `TransformStreams` and `TextDecoderStream` (which is a subclass of TransformStream) as well as decoding the UTF-16LE your input data is using.

First, remember that you're reading a binary stream (that means the basic unit is bytes). When you read a stream, the browser gives you chunks of the stream as they become available (as long as you've already consumed the previous chunk). How the stream is divided into chunks is quite arbitrary (for example, you may get chunks of 64kb, or, on a laggy connection, however much was in each TCP packet).

Before you even get a chance to fail at parsing a CSV line, you're reading UTF-16 so you can just fail at parsing characters. That's because UTF-16 encodes each character as two or more bytes, and there is a chance that some chunks of the input stream will end in the middle of a character.

You can avoid that error by passing `{stream:true}` as options to `TextDecoder.decode` and carrying the unread bytes to the next chunk. But there is a better way.

Instead of getting a reader on the original stream, you [pipe it through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/pipeThrough) a [TextDecoderStream](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#textdecoderstream):

```js
const decoder = new TextDecoderStream('utf-16le')
const characterStream = stream.body.pipeThrough(decoder)
```

Now, when you get a reader on `characterStream`, you don't have to worry about characters. The next part concerns CSV parsing. Obviously, if a stream can be divided in the middle of a character, it can be divided in the middle of a CSV line. In the same fashion as before, you need a TransformStream that reads from a character stream and outputs lines, and the internals of that stream should take care of carrying over unfinished lines to the next chunk.

There is no native solution for that like there is for text decoding, but there are existing implementations, I'll let you look for them and pick one.

Once you've got a stream of lines, you could pipe it through a CSV parser or get a Reader. Either way, with the TransformStreams you won't need to worry about errors caused by how the data is chunked.

Comment: many thanks for your reply, this is helpful. Will using `getReader()` on  `characterStream` ensure that the chunks of data will be complete, meaning that part of chunk will not be present in the next chunk. I am passing the output of `decoder.decode(value, {stream: true})` to a writableStream which generates the CSV. Do i need to implement something before passing data to writableStream which ensures that csv does not contain incomplete lines. sorry for the follow up questions as i indicated earlier i am new to implementing and learning about streams

Comment: You'll never have overlapping chunks with any kind of stream, so yes. And yes, as I have said in my answer, you need to use something to ensure the lines you pass to your CSV parser are complete. [This library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-stream-tools#parsing-data-on-a-stream-which-is-expected-to-be-in-a-specific-format) has a "readLine()" method that should work for you.